# Format specific words in a Google Slide using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm trying to extract a word from a Google Slide and replace its formatting. I was able to do it with this custom function, but it works only with the text that is selected :

```
function formatSelectedText() {
  var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  var textRange = selection.getTextRange();
  if (textRange) {
    var textStyle = textRange.getTextStyle();
    textStyle.setFontSize(11).setFontFamily('Arial');
  } else {
    Logger.log('No text selected or invalid selection.');
  }
}
```

But I would like the function to find words and replace formatting without having to select anything manually on the Google slide.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly guess your actual Google Slide, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If my guess was not correct and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Google Slide? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: perfect response thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search for a text and want to set the text style to the searched text on Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

In this case, it is required to search all texts in all slides in a Google Slide. In my answer, I check the shapes, the tables, and the groups including the shapes and the tables. But, unfortunately, I do not know your Google Slides. So, this is just my guess. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please set your search text.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var searchText = "sample"; // Please set your search text.

  var setStyle_ = text => {
    const search = text.find(searchText);
    if (search.length == 0) return;
    search.forEach(se => se.getTextStyle().setFontSize(11).setFontFamily('Arial'));
  }
  var checkTable_ = table => {
    for (let r = 0; r < table.getNumRows(); r++) {
      const row = table.getRow(r);
      for (let c = 0; c < row.getNumCells(); c++) {
        setStyle_(row.getCell(c).getText());
      }
    }
  }
  var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => setStyle_(shape.getText()));
    slide.getTables().forEach(checkTable_);
    slide.getGroups().forEach(g => {
      g.getChildren().forEach(c => {
        const type = c.getPageElementType();
        if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE) {
          setStyle_(c.asShape().getText());
        } else if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.TABLE) {
          checkTable_(c.asTable());
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, `searchText` is searched from all slides in the active Google Slide. And, the text style of the searched text is changed. From your showing script, `setFontSize(11).setFontFamily('Arial')` is used as the text style.

#### References:

- [getShapes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getshapes)
- [getTables()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#gettables)
- [getGroups()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getgroups)